# Menu bootstrap não funciona, segundo o codigo fornecido pelo site

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap

No `head` está assim:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/icone.png"/>

    <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

No arquivo `script.js` está a função `collapse`:

```
 $('.collapse').collapse();
```

E o código copiado é este:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>
           <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
          </form>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
```

E no final resulta nisto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por que você está carregando o jquery 2.1.3 e também o 3.1.0?

Comment: para teste , mas mesmo deixando um ou outro não funciona

Comment: Colei o seu HTML em um [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jaderw/yonuz5h7/1/) e ele funcionou normalmente. Provavelmente seus arquivos css ou js não estão sendo carregados corretamente.

Comment: Provavelmente o caminho das folhas e scripts não estão sendo encontrados...Tente colocar mais uma contra barra no caminho das folhas de css e js, por exemplo: `href="/css/bootstrap-theme.css"`. Por ser bootstrap, ao menos o `button` seria carregado com o layout padrão de bootstrap, então tira a possibilidade de ser um problema apenas do script. Corrija os caminhos que é quase certo de ser isso

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, o Bootstap não funciona com jQuery superior a 3.0.0

Considere usar uma versão anterior estável.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize o CDN

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```